# Número máximo de opções dentro da tag <c:choose> do JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, front-end, jstl

Pessoal recentemente estava trabalhando com JSTL e me deparei com a seguinte situação, eu tentei adicionar 3 tags when dentro de uma tag choose e a última tag simplesmente não funciona, o código estava assim:

```xml
<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${pagina != null}">
            <c:import url="${pagina}.jsp"></c:import>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${mensagem != null}">
            <br><p><c:out value="${mensagem}"></c:out></p>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${salvarTodosCertificados != null}">
            <p>Caso queira baixar todos os certificados em zip:</p> <br>
            Clique <a href="site?comando=gerarCertificado&quantos=todos">aqui</a>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
```

O número máximo de tags when que eu posso colocar dentro de uma tag choose é realmente 2?

Tive que substituir o código acima por este:

```xml
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${pagina != null}">
            <c:import url="${pagina}.jsp"></c:import>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${mensagem != null}">
            <br><p><c:out value="${mensagem}"></c:out></p>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${salvarTodosCertificados != null}">
            <p>Caso queira baixar todos os certificados em zip:</p> <br>
            Clique <a href="site?comando=gerarCertificado&quantos=todos">aqui</a>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
```

Isso procede ou configurei algo errado ou sei lá?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O número de cláusulas dentro do `<c:choose>` é, para efeitos práticos, ilimitado.

Porém, parece que você não entendeu muito a ideia do `<c:choose>`. Ele funciona de forma semelhantes a um `if` cheio de `else if`s.

No caso do primeiro código, o que você fez é mais ou menos isso:

```
if (pagina != null) {
    // ...
} else if (mensagem != null) {
   // ...
} else if (salvarTodosCertificados != null) {
   // ...
}
```

Já o segundo, é mais ou menos isso:

```
if (pagina != null) {
    // ...
} else if (mensagem != null) {
   // ...
}
if (salvarTodosCertificados != null) {
   // ...
}
```

Observe que cada cláusula `<c:when>` é análoga a um `if` ou `else if`. Se você tivesse um `<c:otherwise>`, ele seria análogo ao `else`.

Em uma estrutura `if ... else if ... else if ...`, apenas o primeiro `if` que tiver a condição satisfeita executa. Mesmo se algum dos `if`s mais abaixo também pudesse ser satisfeito, apenas o primeiro que for satisfeito executa. O mesmo acontece com o `<c:choose>`.

Assim sendo, o seu problema parece ser que você esperava que o `<c:when>` da condição `salvarTodosCertificados != null` fosse executado mesmo quando uma das condições de um dos `<c:when>`s acima também fosse, o que não irá acontecer por causa do fato de que é executado apenas o primeiro para o qual a condição é verdadeira. Ou então, você esperava que os dois primeiros fossem falsos quando um deles é verdadeiro. Ou então, colocou os seus `<c:when>` na ordem errada.